# How to convert a inline assembly in a header file function to c++ function without assembly to support x64?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

Can anyone help with converting the following inline assemly in a header file to corresponding x86-64 .asm file or c style function without assembly?

```
extern const char hexlu[];
void _inline hextoascii(char* a_src , char* a_dest ) {
_asm {

              mov esi, a_src;
    mov edi, a_dest;
    sub ebx,ebx

    mov edx,[esi+00]
    mov bl,dl
    mov ax,word ptr [ebx*2+hexlu]
    mov [edi+00],ax
};
}
```

Comment: Do you want C or C++ ? They are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void hextoascii(char* src, char* dest)
{
    dest[0] = hexlu[  2*(unsigned)src[0]];
    dest[1] = hexlu[1+2*(unsigned)src[0]];
}
```

Comment: No check on boundaries as in ASM version :)

Comment: My ASM is rusty, but it looks to me like it's a 256-byte lookup table, and there is thus only one reference to it.  (And one wonders what the point is of making it ASM.)

Comment: `*(short*)dest = *(((short*)hexlu) + *src);` or thereabouts.  (Assuming short is 16 bits.)

Comment: @Hot_Licks a 512 bytes lookup table I think (2 chars for every byte value)

Comment: If this is really a conversion from a 1-byte value to a 2-character hexadecimal ASCII representation then this can be done much better/simpler than a 512-byte lookup table. See my answer.

Comment: @HotLicks - We all know that writing code in assembly makes it amazingly FAST. Magic! That's why.

Comment: @BoPersson - Definitely.  Even though an optimizing compiler would probably produce nearly the identical code.

Comment: @BoPersson: +1 for irony :-)

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, I'd suggest to simply use [`itoa()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), like:

```
static inline void hextoasacii(char *a_src, char *a_dest)
{
    (void)itoa(*a_src, a_dest, 16);
}
```

but this has the disadvantage that `a_dest` will become `NULL`-terminated by this, i.e. it needs three (not two) bytes of space, so this isn't 100% equivalent.

The inline assembly code shown isn't particularly optimal regarding memory accesses in any case; a raw form (but it of course depends on the exact contents of your 255-entry sized `hexlu[]` array, I'm assuming it looks like `char *hexlu[] = { "00", "01", "02", ... };`) in C/C++ would be:

```
static inline void hextoascii(char *a_src, char *a_dest)
{
    static const char hexdigits[16] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int src = *a_src;
    a_dest[0] = hexdigits[src >> 4];
    a_dest[1] = hexdigits[src & 15];

    // make this:
    // *(unsigned short*)a_dest =
    //     ((unsigned short)hexdigits[src & 15]) << 8 |
    //     (unsigned short)hexdigits[src >> 4]
    //
    // if it absolutely _must_ be a single store
}
```

**Side note:**

if you really want to go the assembly way for binary/hexadecimal conversion, there are ways to code the above using SSSE3 (`pshufb`) for the 16-character table lookup. With that, the equivalent of `sprintf("%llx", tgt_string, val_uint64)` can be done in essentially a *single* `pshufb` instruction.

Examples how to do this and explanations how it works are found here:

- Read the following thread on binary/hex conversion on the [Flat Assembler Board](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9432) (search for BitRake's post using `pshufb`)
- Read [Wojciech Muła's](http://0x80.pl/) article on [using SSSE3 for printing hex values](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-hexprint.html) (code here: [`hexdump.c`](http://wm.ite.pl/snippets/asm/hexprint.c)); also suggest reading his article on speeding up `itoa(..., 10)` using similarly interesting techniques

An SSSE3 solution, for doing it byte-by-byte, won't provide as big a speedup as converting multiple bytes in one go because only 1/8th of the `XMM` register would be used; your function cannot (efficiently) be converted to use SSSE3 as-is. In case you're calling it in a loop though (to print a hexdump of a memory region), then using a function like Wojciech's example code will provide a very significant speedup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to convert the 32-bit pointers to 64-bit pointers.

```
extern const char hexlu[];
void _inline hextoascii(char* a_src , char* a_dest ) {
_asm {
    mov rsi, a_src;
    mov rdi, a_dest;
    sub rbx, rbx;

    mov rdx, [rsi];
    mov bl, dl;
    mov ax, [2*rbx+hexlu];
    mov [rdi], ax;
};
}
```

Comment: Changing to 64 bit registers will not help me in my situation but thanks anyway.